# Where can I find a tutorial/example or help on "Octree" with XNA?

Tags: graphics, matrix, xna, minecraft, octree

I am developing a small minecraft style game on XNA.
I generates a voxel mode, so I'm looking to be optimized to the maximum my matrix "World"!
This is the one I'm looking for example "**How to Use Octree with Xna ?**." Unfortunately, I have not found a tutorial on this on google or other ... I find this strange, because this technology is much used!

I wish I could turn my 100x100x100 matrix containing for each box a bit (1 or 0) indicating whether or not there is a block.
Is this a tutorial "Octree" I need to do this?
Or can someone show me an example of a transformation matrix3D to a Octree matrice ?

Thousand thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Static Octree in XNA](http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php/Octree), [Loose Octree in XNA](http://ploobs.com.br/?p=1622) , [Another Loose Octree in XNA](http://octtree.codeplex.com/).